# What is the difference between Provider and Resolver

Tags: oop, design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming

I often need a class/service that will give me some data trough fetching it from a DB, transforming an existing data structure or do both internally but I sometimes have a difficulty naming them properly.

I am currently working with [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius) and they are using classes/services with suffixes such as `Checker`, `Applicator`, `Processor`... I have clear understanding of these names and their implications as to what and how they are doing things. But there are also suffixes `Provider` and `Resolver` and I have a difficulty differentiating between them. I don't understand the exact differences of their naming.

What I observed is:

- **Provider**: fetching data that are not yet available (internally fetching data from DB or external API)
- **Resolver**: I already have a bunch of data (and I don't need any additional data) and I need to filter, transform or get some subset of it.

Is there some convention or design pattern to names `Resolver` and `Provider`? Am I somewhat right here? Or is there more nuance to this naming?

Comment: This is a totally opinion-based situation. You can name your classes anything you want unless it is part of a framework, where naming conventions are used. For example `MyRouteController` in Asp.net Web Api framework, will make a convention-based route `MyRoute`.

Answer (score 2):

In my view, patterns are not depend on technology or language, so [this article can be applied here](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html):

> Content Providers provide an interface, e.g. for publishing and consuming data

and:

> Content Resolver resolves a publishing and consuming data to a specific Content provider.
> The Content Resolver includes the CRUD (create, read, update, delete) methods corresponding to the abstract methods (insert, query, update, delete) in the Content Provider class.

**UPDATE**

`Provider` is an abstraction that can be implemented by concrete providers. E.g., there is `DataProvider` and `DataProvider` is an abstraction. So we want  concrete implementations of SqlServerProvider, PostgreProvider, OracleProvider.

Let me show an example via C#:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    string GetById();
}

public class SqlServerProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public string GetById()
    {
        return "Data retrieved with SqlServerProvider";
    }
}

public class PostgreProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public string GetById()
    {
        return "Data retrieved with PostgreProvider";
    }
}


public class OracleProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public string GetById()
    {
        return "Data retrieved with OracleProvider";
    }
}
```

Then we need to resolve the above dependenies to use them. But how? We can create `DataResolver`:

```
public enum DataProviderType
{
    SqlServer, Posgre, Oracle
}

public class DataResolver
{
    private Dictionary<DataProviderType, IDataProvider> _dataProviderByType =
        new Dictionary<DataProviderType, IDataProvider>()
        {
            { DataProviderType.SqlServer, new SqlServerProvider() },
            { DataProviderType.Posgre, new PostgreProvider() },
            { DataProviderType.Oracle, new OracleProvider() },
        };

    public IDataProvider Resolve(DataProviderType dataProviderType) 
    {
        return _dataProviderByType[dataProviderType];
    }    
}
```

and then we can run the above code like this:

```
DataResolver dataResolver = new DataResolver();
string someValue = dataResolver.Resolve(DataProviderType.SqlServer).GetById();
Console.WriteLine(someValue); // OUTPUT: Data retrieved with SqlServerProvider
```

[See more examples of code here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm#)

Comment: Soooo... Provider is high-level agregator of resolvers? Would it be correct to have ArticleProvider that would have an (DatabaseBased)ArticleResolver as an constructor dependency (for example...)?

Comment: @MartinSršeň please, see my updated answer